# Run jQuery after another jQuery script

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using `curl` to fetch the HTML from anothe web page and display on one of my pages:

```
$("document").ready(function() {

    $("#content").load("curl.php .auction_list_closed");

});
```

Once the content is returned I want to have another script run. How can I run another line of jQuery once the content has been loaded?

Comment: any reason why not to fetch the HTML directly?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the `.auction_list_closed` representative of? I've not seen that syntax before.

Answer (score 4):

The `.load()` function accepts, as the second parameter, a function which is executed once completed.

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    $("#content").load("curl.php .auction_list_closed", function(){
         startSecondScript();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

add your code in the callback method

```
$("#content").load("curl.php .auction_list_closed", function() {
  //do your stuff here.
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a callback to the `load()` method as a parameter: http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
$("#content").load("curl.php .auction_list_closed", function() { 
    // do work
});
```

or

```
$("#content").load("curl.php .auction_list_closed", myCallback);

function myCallback() {
    // do work
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure, but i believe you can simply add an callback function. More info can be found [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

For example:

```
$("document").ready(function() {

    $("#content").load("curl.php .auction_list_closed", function() {alert("data was loaded")});

});
```